# How do I construct and pass raw json data with okHttpClient in android

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using a query where I need to POST to an endpoint with okhttpclient.
The issue is I have the payload value and the senttime. I just don't know how to create a json object to send over as a raw body object to the endpoint.
To make things more clear:
here's my postman screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXZoX.png)

This is my post request :
https://example.org/api/service-profile/v1/device-notification/`{deviceId}`
Now I am planning to pass {deviceId} in the path, authorization token in the header and finally , as raw payload query like this in the body :

```json
    {
      "payload": {"notificationID":"677291f5-a784-43df-af2e-0363a4067e9c","title":"test 223","body":"payload","lockScreenVisibility":1,"groupMessage":"","fromProjectNumber":"819539062812","priority":5,"rawPayload":"{\"google.delivered_priority\":\"normal\",\"google.sent_time\":1591849563191,\"google.ttl\":259200,\"google.original_priority\":\"normal\",\"custom\":\"{\\\"i\\\":\\\"677291f5-a784-43df-af2e-0363a4067e9c\\\"}\",\"oth_chnl\":\"\",\"pri\":\"5\",\"abc\":\"1\",\"from\":\"819539062812\",\"alert\":\"payload\",\"title\":\"test 223\",\"grp_msg\":\"\",\"google.message_id\":\"0:1591849563205759%409ebbcaf9fd7ecd\",\"google.c.sender.id\":\"819539062812\",\"notificationId\":-1451117355}"}
    ,
      "sentTime": 1591849563191
    }
```

trouble is I have the payload value and senttime, but I dont know how to construct a json object such that i can create the structure as { "payload" :**pass in my payload value**, "senttime":**pass in sent time**}
and then pass it as a raw body param over okhttpclient? Any idea how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create a model for your payload and pass the object as `@Body` to your Retrofit API

Comment: Can you update the question to add the code for retrofit?

Comment: That's one of the parts I need help with , constructing a retrofit query with okhttpclient with the raw payload as above